Expo / React Native: Allow user to take screenshot of the whole page on iOS
I'm currently having trouble understanding how i can allow users to take screenshots of the whole page on iOS - because in some apps (Safari, ..) it's possible to take such a screenshot and well i thought it could be a feature that is only available to apple itself, but now i've seen the chatgpt app also allows this
So the behaviour i'm talking about is that after a screenshot is made - the user can open the screenshot and has a small navigation between "screen" and "full page" as can be seen here for instance: https://www.cultofmac.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/01/Screenshot-Full-Page.jpg


You may enable users to take a screenshot of the entire screen in React Native apps like yours. However, capturing a complete webpage is not a native iOS functionality.

You'd need to implement a customised solution.

Use a ScrollView or FlatList to render the content that could potentially be longer than the screen height.
import { captureRef } from 'react-native-view-shot';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';

// Capture full page
const captureFullPage = async () => {
try {
  let fullPageImageUri = '';

  // Assuming `scrollRef` is a ref to the scrollable container
  const localUri = await captureRef(scrollRef, {
    format: 'jpg', 
    quality: 1,
    result: 'tmpfile', // Save as temporary file
  });

  fullPageImageUri = localUri;

   // Options save to gallery
   await MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(fullPageImageUri);
    alert('Full Page Screenshot Saved!');
  }  catch (e) {
    console.error("Error capturing full page", e);
  }
};

return (
  <ScrollView ref={scrollRef} style={styles.scrollView}>
    {/* Your page content here */}
  </ScrollView>
);


I recently read the documentation that Expo has provided, and there is a source code that shows us how the screenshot functionality actually works : https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/screenshot/


